# Drawing text with gradient fill in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, text, drawing, gradient

I have a project that needs to draw text in a view with a gradient fill in a custom subclass of NSView, like this example below.

[image]

I'm wondering how I can achieve this, as I'm pretty new to Cocoa drawing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [creating an alpha mask from the text](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/09/creating-alpha-masks-from-text-on.html) then using NSGradient to draw into it.  Here's a simple example based on the linked code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    // Create a grayscale context for the mask
    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    CGContextRef maskContext =
    CGBitmapContextCreate(
        NULL,
        self.bounds.size.width,
        self.bounds.size.height,
        8,
        self.bounds.size.width,
        colorspace,
        0);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);

    // Switch to the context for drawing
    NSGraphicsContext *maskGraphicsContext =
        [NSGraphicsContext
            graphicsContextWithGraphicsPort:maskContext
            flipped:NO];
    [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
    [NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext:maskGraphicsContext];

    // Draw the text right-way-up (non-flipped context)
    [text
        drawInRect:rect
        withAttributes:
            [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                [NSFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:124], NSFontAttributeName,
                [NSColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
            nil]];

    // Switch back to the window's context
    [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];

    // Create an image mask from what we've drawn so far
    CGImageRef alphaMask = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(maskContext);

    // Draw a white background in the window
    CGContextRef windowContext = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
    [[NSColor whiteColor] setFill];
    CGContextFillRect(windowContext, rect);

    // Draw the gradient, clipped by the mask
    CGContextSaveGState(windowContext);
    CGContextClipToMask(windowContext, NSRectToCGRect(self.bounds), alphaMask);

    NSGradient *gradient = [[NSGradient alloc] initWithStartingColor:[NSColor blackColor] endingColor:[NSColor grayColor]];
    [gradient drawInRect:rect angle:-90];
    [gradient release];

    CGContextRestoreGState(windowContext);
    CGImageRelease(alphaMask);
}
```

This uses the view bounds as the gradient bounds; if you wanted to be more accurate, you'd need to get the text height (information about that [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextLayout/Tasks/StringHeight.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001809-CJBGBIBB)).

Comment: Thank you! I've also found a category from Apple's sample code (SpeedometerView) for NSString which converts a string to a bezier path, the rest of the thing is simply transform the path and fill it with gradient.